# Closing SwipeRow inside FlatList using Native-Base

Tags: react-native, native-base

How can I close SwipeRow inside FlatList?

This is the easy thing to do with ListView, but since the next release is going to use FlatList it should be possible.

From reading their source code, it seems like it is not implemented yet.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

can you try this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { FlatList } from 'react-native';
import { Container, Header, Content, SwipeRow, View, Text, Icon, Button } from 'native-base';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { data: [{ key: 'a' }, { key: 'b' }] }
    this.component = [];
    this.selectedRow;
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Header />
        <Content>
          <FlatList
            data={[{ key: 'a', value: 'Row one' }, { key: 'b', value: 'Row two' }, { key: 'c', value: 'Row three' }, { key: 'd', value: 'Row four' }, { key: 'e', value: 'Row five' }]}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.key}
            renderItem={({ item }) => <SwipeRow
              ref={(c) => { this.component[item.key] = c }}
              leftOpenValue={75}
              rightOpenValue={-75}
              onRowOpen={() => {
                if (this.selectedRow && this.selectedRow !== this.component[item.key]) { this.selectedRow._root.closeRow(); }
                this.selectedRow = this.component[item.key]
              }}
              left={
                <Button success onPress={() => alert('Add')}>
                  <Icon active name="add" />
                </Button>
              }
              body={
                <View style={{ paddingLeft: 20 }}>
                  <Text>{item.value}</Text>
                </View>
              }
              right={
                <Button danger onPress={() => alert('Delete')}>
                  <Icon active name="trash" />
                </Button>
              }
            />}
          />
          <Button style={{ margin: 20 }} onPress={() => this.selectedRow._root.closeRow()}><Text>Close row</Text></Button>
        </Content>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You're an absolute beast! Thanks kind Sir.! This should be taken as the answer.

Comment: getting error ```TypeError : undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this._panResponder.panHandlers')```

Comment: @chiragprajapati SwipeRow has been removed from native-base from v2.13.0 onwards.